# ¿Cómo detectar si mi consulta es nula?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Tengo el siguiente problema, quisiera detectar si esta consulta da `NULL` en `sqlite3`, para luego manejar el resultado en Python. Leí que si da `NULL` devuelve como resultado `1`, poniendo `NULL` al final de la consulta. He visto otros ejemplo con `IS NULL`, pero no está funcionando ya que al llegar al `if` lo salta, entiendo que no esta devolviendo `1` al no encontrar el registro con un `id` en concreto que puedo hacer la consulta y luego aplicar `fetchall` para obtener todos los registros, pero lo que quiero es aplicar luego de esta consulta `fetch one` para no ocupar tanta memoria, entonces si puedo detectar cuando el `id` da como resultado `NULL` puedo ver como manejarlo.

```
def select_row():

    x = self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT ISNULL(( SELECT id FROM preceptores WHERE id={x.index+1}), NULL)')

    if x == 1:
        print('es nulo')

    return x
```

Comment: Ya probaste con `IFNULL` en vez de `ISNULL`

Comment: ya probaste haciendola como corresponde, por ejemplo con un count para ahorrarte todo este desbande????

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que nunca te va a dar `NULL`. Algunas consideraciones con respecto a lo que has intentado:

- `_cursor.execute()` no debería por que retornar ningún dato, simplemente ejecuta la sentencia que le pasas.
- Entiendo que lo que buscas es validar que la consulta traiga datos, pero no lo vas a conseguir de la forma en que lo estás haciendo, un `select` que no trae filas invalida cualquier cosa que intentes hacer luego, en `SQL` plano podemos usar el `COUNT()` para contar las filas (como ya te mencionaron) o incluso mejor si el motor lo permite, la clausula `EXISTS`
- Pero en tu caso, entiendo que bastaría chequear los resultados obtenidos, mediante el `fetchall` o similar:

---

```
resultados = self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT ...')
resultados = self._cursor.fetchall()
if not resultados:
    print('No hemos obtenido filas')
```

Por otro lado, un tema de concepto, el resultado de una consulta nunca es `NULL`, o hay filas o no las hay, el `NULL` es eventualmente una condición de una o más columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método `len()` de esa forma:

```
resultados = self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT ...')
resultados = self._cursor.fetchall()
if len(resultados) == 0:
    print('No hemos obtenido filas')
else:
    for row in resultados:
       print(row)
```

Si solo necesita verificar si la consulta devolvió alguna fila puede ser más eficiente usar `fetchone()` en vez de `fetchall()`, porque devuelve `None` si no encuentra nada.

https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/